# Sorting on long float field does not work correctly (ES 1.3.4)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with incorrect sorting based on float type field. I have a float type field in my data called `gtd_sort_number` (see data example below). Value is a microtime so it's quite long with decimal values (as on example below). Now when I do a query like below (2nd example), the result set is not  sorted correctly. Some items are in correct order some not. First example shows data returned from query so you can see `"sort": [1412944380]` added to the result. This seems to me that ES rounds the former values somehow and then sorts it so it produces wrong results because it rounds different(similar) values  to the same value.

Any idea what's wrong here?

```
{
  "_index": "netnotes",
  "_type": "activity",
  "_id": "a53ab53ba52b3f03bf8e547a0633dc3f",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "id": "a53ab53ba52b3f03bf8e547a0633dc3f",
    "gtd_sort_number": 1412944355.6989,
    "gtd_section_id": "37aee9eb-e836-41f1-89a8-8d173fe23d57",
    "gtd_board_id": "0d7b113b24d53a5a9ca50345173c4c49",
    "gtd_color": "#000000",
    "gtd_type": "note",
    "gtd_label": "",
    "gtd_private": null
  },
  "sort": [
    1412944380
  ]
}
```

Query example

```
GET /netnotes/activity/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "gtd_board_id": "0d7b113b24d53a5a9ca50345173c4c49"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "gtd_sort_number": "desc"
  },
  "from": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the float is not able to hold your number, meaning it doesn't have the necessary precision and number of bits to hold that number.
You may want to change the mapping from "float" to "double".

Comment: Tried the double type already but ES raises error when sorting by this field.

Comment: Hm. Can you update your post with the error and the mapping, please? I tried a simple mapping with a double field and was able to sort successfully.